# How to I get the input from the HTML to link to the MyChecker function? It doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, function

This is the code I used. It takes the first name and the surname from the user and then uses them in the MyChecker function where it matches up the names used to create different alerts. I can't get the MyChecker function to link to the values inputted by the user?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Question 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>What's your name?</p>
    <form action="action.php"> //This form gets the input from the user
        First Name
        <br><input type="text" name="FirstName" value="" id="txt1"><br>
        Second Name
        <br><input type="text" name="SecondName" value="" id="txt2"><br>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() { //This function gets the values inputted by the user
  document.getElementById('txt1').value);
  document.getElementById('txt2').value);
}
var x= FirstName.localeCompare("Donald");
var y= SecondName.localeCompare("Trump");
MyChecker();

function MyChecker()
{
  if(x==0&&y==0)
  {
    alert("I love the poorly educated");
  }

  var a= FirstName.localeCompare("Edward");
  var b= SecondName.localeCompare("Snowden");

  if(a==0 && b==0)
  {
    var ask=prompt("Would you mind collecting your cake from our office in Pennsylvania?","Choose between yes or no");
    var cmp=ask.localeCompare("yes");
    if(cmp==0)
    {
      alert("We'll even reimburse your plane tickets!");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("Perhaps next time...");
    }
  }

  if(a!=0 && b !=0 && x !=0 && y!=0)
  {
    alert("Carry on...");
  } 
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I touched up your indentation and hopefully it helps to expose the issue.  When you submit the form, you will call `myFunction`, which I've copied here for clarity:

```
function myFunction() { //This function gets the values inputted by the user
  document.getElementById('txt1').value);
  document.getElementById('txt2').value);
}
```

... and that's it.  These values aren't even saved.

You probably mean to have `myFunction` call `MyChecker`, so that your logic will be executed each time the form is submitted.

You might also consider having `MyChecker` take in the `FirstName` and `SecondName` as parameters, since `myFunction` is already reading values from the form.